# Trying to Mock the Microsoft Exchange Web Service

Tags: c#, mocking, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to test my application, which is using the Microsoft Exchange Web Service dll to access an Exchange Server.

I want to isolate my application from a need for an actual Exchange Server in my tests, and i realized i cannot mock the Exchange DLL...

Another problem, is that i cannot change the operational code, which does not use an interface or an adapter to access the Exchange Web Service DLL, therefore i cannot simply stub it...

In my research i found the Microsoft Moles framework, which allows me to Mole and replace any method (even constructors) with my own delegate. However, i found that in the application code, we're using internal Microsoft data types (for example **[EmailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd634030%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx)**) that do not allow much freedom of how to create them or change them.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to what i can do in such a situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If i where you i would try to **hide exchange behind an email service [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)** and replace all code that is directly referenceing exchange with calls to that facade.

Mockin the facade is much easier than mocking exchange itself.

As a sideeffect if customer decides to use some other email system you just have to reimplement the facade instead of changing the whole application.

Comment: @Yiftach - if you can't change the code then it's not your application, and hopes of isolating it are unrealistic. If your job title says "Tester" you may want to look at [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/typemock-isolator-product3/).

Comment: In this case you can't use a facade to deal with the problem, anyhow.  You can't pass the facade into a Bind call as it's not typed as an ExchangeService.  Using a facade and passing through the calls to ExchangeService only gets you halfway there.